# passing a function a specific array index value

Tags: c++, msp430

Ive been coding in c and I have an array which is just a `char array[22]`,
I can successfully populate the array with data. there are a few numeric values in the array and i want to check if they fall within a certain range i.e greater than `0` and less than `10` etc.
I have a function, `void array_check(testarray[])` declare before the `main`. 
the function is being called inside the `main` i.e. `array_check(testarray[9])`
So this should pass the function index number `9`, and the function should check if the value of index `9` is between a range etc.

I can't get the program to compile properly. in the function declaration I would have thought the it would be something like this `void array_check(testarray[i])` where when I call the function in the `main` the I would denote the index to check. The compiler tells me that the function decaration and the function itself should have a constant value. It wont allow me to leave the `[i]` value in the square brackets.  any ideas?
thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

If you call `check(array[9])`, you're just passing the char stored at index 9 in the array, and your function should be declared as

```
void check(char);
```

Once you've indexed an array of any type to get the element at that index, there's nothing magically *arrayish* about the element - it's just a normal object of that type (in this case a `char`).

Comment: Hi,Thank you for the speedy reply, Ive declared the function as void array_check(char), I am calling the function like array_check(testarray[4]) etc. where the function itself begins the compiler says  "unnamed prototyped parameters not allowed when body is present"

Comment: I just showed the function declaration - if you're defining it, you need to give that character argument a name. You should also be posting your actual code in questions rather than a wall of text, it's much easier to read. And, finally, this is pretty basic stuff - I have to recommend you try a book or tutorial or something, learning from this level by asking questions will take a long time.